# Real analysis: Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space with norm $|| \cdot ||$ . Let $X_o$ be a dense subspace of $X$. Assume that $X_o$, when normed by the norm it inherits from $X$, is also a Banach space. Prove that $X=X_o$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is a bit trivial. I will give the main idea of the proof and you will make a "textbook proof" out of it (if required).

Take any point $x$ in $X$. Since $X_0$ is dense, $x$ is an limit point of $X_0$ and therefore, there is a sequence in $X_0$ which converges to $x$ in $X$. Therefore, this sequence must be Cauchy. Since $X_0$ is considered to be Banach space, $x$ must belong to $X_0$ thereby proving the equality as required.